# MongoDB as a cache: performance settings

Tags: mongodb

I'm working on a part of a system, which uses MongoDB as a cache (operational data, which can be restored if needed).

For this type of workload it is ok to disable all replication and disaster-recovery mechanisms in sake of performance.

Our current results for 1M bulk insert / update / delete are the following:
https://github.com/sqshq/mongodb-benchmark

The only "tuning" option we tried is to disable journaling on the server side.

Are there any other less-known crazy settings on `mongod` or driver side, which can increase performance? (except "fire and forget" query mode)

Comment: What’s your main datastore if you’re using mongo as cache?

Comment: Mostly Neo4j and MongoDB (another installation for non-operational data). When I say "cache", I mean "data, which we change frequently but don't afraid to lose". This part of the system is idempotent, we can just reset kafka offset to restore "cache" for disaster recovery. We heavily rely on some mongodb index, query and concurrency related features, that's why more traditional cache systems (redis, memcahced, etc) are not an option for now

Comment: And you are interested in write performance? Have you considered Cassandra?